# React MUI useStyles not updated on state change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles, use-state

I am using a custom hook that returns two `booleans` which I'm passing to `useStyles` as props. The problem is that when the state of those booleans change - `useStyles` does not update the style of the component.

Component:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ children }) => {
    const {boolean1, boolean2} = useCustomHook();

    const classes = useStyles({ boolean1, boolean2 });

    return (
        <Box className={classes.content}>{children}</Box>
    )
```

Style:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, StyleProps>((theme) => ({
    content: {
        display: 'flex',
        minHeight: ({ boolean1, boolean2 }) => {
           const offsetY =
               boolean1 && !boolean2
                   ? 100
                   : 200
           return `calc(100vh - ${offsetY}px) !important`;
    },
}));
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Replace `useStyles({ isAdvanced, isProtected })` with `useStyles({ boolean1, boolean2 })`

Comment: This wasn't the issue - I mistyped it here. It's like you suggested in the code already.